# I need add data one by one in List Model from firebase realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

## I got this error when am trying to add the results in the list

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>

## my code is

```
List<roomsModel> room2 = [];
  Future<void> loadProjImgs() async {
    ref = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Booking');
    final snapshot = await ref.get();
    if (snapshot.exists) {
      await ref.child('date').child('27-6-2022')
          .onValue.forEach((element) {
         //print(element.snapshot.value.toString());
         print(element.snapshot.children.map((e) {
           print(e.value);

           final data = e.value;
           room2.add(roomsModel.fromJson(e.value));
         }));
         //room2.add(roomsModel.fromJson(element.snapshot.value));
      });
      
    } else {
      print('No data available.');
    }

  }
```

## then I'll add the model to the Widget

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
await ref.get().then(
        (event) {
      final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.value);
      data.forEach(
            (key, value) {
          var room = roomsModel.fromJson(value)
        },
      );
    },
  );
```

Comment: it doesn't work also I got ***The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.*** in event.value